# ¿Cómo hacer un login en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Buenos Dias,

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en PHP ( login ) con base de datos pero no me loguea

Este es mi codigo :

```
    <?php
$usuario = $_POST['nnpmbre'];
$pass = $_POST['npassword'];

if (empty($usuario) || empty($pass)) {
  # code...
  header("location: ../index.html");
  exit();
}

mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678') or die ("Error al Conectar, Usuario o clave incorrectos" .mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db('web_juegos') or die("Error, lo sentimos en estos momentos tenemos problemas en la base de datos porfavor intente mas tarde" .mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * from User0 ='".$usuario ."'");

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

  if($row['Password'] == $pass){

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header("location: mensaje.php");
  }else{
    header("location: ../index.html");
    exit();
  }
}else{
  header("location: ../index.html");
}

 ?>
```

Ya, logre loguearme `if (empty($usuario) || empty($pass)) {
  # code...
  header("location: ../index.html");
  exit();
}`

ese codigo me recargaba la pagina al momento de iniciar la session, lo arregle y me salio esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es la linea 13:

```
mysqli_select_db('web_juegos') or die("Error, lo sentimos en estos momentos tenemos problemas en la base de datos porfavor intente mas tarde" .mysqli_error());
```

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: Creo que tu consulta está mal "SELECT * from User0 ='".$usuario ."'"

Comment: el problema es que ni siquiera me dice donde esta el error :(

Comment: Debería ser algo similar a esto "SELECT * from User0 where usuario = '".$usuario ."'"

Comment: Que es lo que te dice de la consulta puedes colocar el error en la pregunta

Comment: Según viendo tu consulta no la tienes completa te falta el where y el nombre del campo por donde vas a buscar o la tabla  por favor coloca todos los datos de la tabla para hacerte el query

Comment: lo que pasa es que ni siquiera me dice que esta la contraseña incorrecta ni nada ... :(

Comment: ostia verdad el where

Comment: saben como puedo resumir mas ese codigo?

Comment: En que sentido lo quieres resumir más

Comment: menos codigo y la misma funcionalidad se podra????

Comment: Puedes probar tu código haciendo un echo en tus validaciones y con eso puedes saber en que bloque se está perdiendo.

Comment: Para simplificarlo un poco puedes usar las variables directamente $_POST['nnpmbre'] y $_POST['npassword'] y tu primera validacion la puedes poner así if( !isset($_POST['nnpmbre']) || !isset($_POST['npassword'] )){.....}

Comment: Coloca una respuesta estos comentarios ya se estan extendiendo mucho XD

Comment: Lo que comenta Jorge es importante primero verifica obtengas los valores correctos: $usuario = $_POST['nnpmbre'];
$pass = $_POST['npassword'];

Comment: Creo que tambien es la clave, la tengo cifrada con MD5 y al parecer creo que tambien debe ser eso no ?

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol    chicos entren al chat para que no se haga muy extenso los comentarios

Comment: Puedes sacar la conexión para un fichero aparte e incluirla así la puedes usar en cualquier parte de tu proyecto la validación la veo bien por que debes comprobar que las variables no vengas vacías eso básicamente es lo que veo para optimizar tu código.

Comment: si les pasa de tener un error y que no se los señale, prueben con var_dump($variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que poner el Where en la consulta

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * from User0 where username ='".$usuario ."'");
```

En este caso username es el nombre de el atributo en la tabla mysql.

Comment: ya lo arregle y sigue igual

Comment: Si tiras esa misma consulta con el literal del nombre de usuario en el phpmyadmin trae alguna fila ?

Comment: porfavor ver la respuesta esta editada

Comment: Lo que se muestra son 2 advertencias sobre la cantidad de parametros que se envían a las funciones, y las que estas están esperando. Te recomiendo darle un repaso a la documentación para estar seguro de que le estás dando el uso e implementación correctas.

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php

http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Gracias :3 te lo agradezco mucho :3

Comment: Esta respuesta es errónea o parcialmente correcta, **mysqli_query** requiere 2 parámetros, no sólo el String de la consulta

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema está en tu query, la tenerla de la siguiente manera:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * from User0 ='".$usuario ."'");
```

Tendrías que cambiarla, te hace falta el where dentro del ella, quedando más o menos así:

```
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * from User0 where usuario ='".$usuario ."'");
```

Comment: ya lo arregle y sigue igual

Comment: podrías poner tu nueva consulta, tu campo en la tabla de User0 si se llama usuario? Yo lo puse sin saber el nombre de ese campo, tal vez ahí está el error o podrías compartir los campos de tu tabla.

Comment: porfavor  ver la respuesta esta editada

Comment: Esta respuesta es errónea o parcialmente correcta, **mysqli_query** requiere 2 parámetros, no sólo el String de la consulta.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$usuario = $_POST['nnpmbre'];
$pass = $_POST['npassword'];

if (empty($usuario) || empty($pass))
{
  header("location: ../index.html");
  // exit no requiere (), es una contruccion del lenguaje
  exit;
}

// mysqli_conect REQUIERE 4 parametros no 3 ejemplo
// $enlace = mysqli_connect("mi_host", "mi_usuario", "mi_contraseña", "mi_bd");
// mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678') or die ("Error al Conectar, Usuario o clave incorrectos" .mysqli_error());
// Tapoco estas almacenando la conexion en ninguna variable para su utilización
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678','web_juegos') or die ("Error al Conectar, Usuario o clave incorrectos" .mysqli_error());

// Es recomendable comprobar si la conexion fue exitosa
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Fall&oacute; la conexi&oacute;n: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

// Es recomendable establecer explicitamente los juegos de caracteres que se van a utilizar
// para no tener problemas futuros
mysqli_query($link, 'SET NAMES utf8') or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_query($link, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8') or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_query($link, 'SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="utf8_general_ci" ') or die(mysql_error());


// podemos prescindir de esta linea ya que indicamos la bd en la conexión
// mysqli_select_db('web_juegos') or die("Error, lo sentimos en estos momentos tenemos problemas en la base de datos porfavor intente mas tarde" .mysqli_error());

// Aquí te falta el WHERE y pasarle la conexión en nuestro ejemplo $link
// $result = mysqli_query("SELECT * from User0 ='".$usuario ."'");
// También estaria bien que como minimo escaparas los datos minimamente
// si solo esperas un resultado añade un LIMIT 1, es innecesario escanear el 100% de la tabla 
// también si solo quieres la Password y el User0 indícalo para no traer mas datos innecesarios
$usuario =mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $usuario);
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT Password,User0 from WHERE User0 ='".$usuario ."' LIMIT 1");

if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // aqui haría una comparacion extricta (===)
    //if($row['Password'] == $pass)
    if($row['Password'] === $pass)
    {
        session_start();
        header("location: mensaje.php");
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $row['User0'];
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: ../index.html");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
  header("location: ../index.html");
}

?>
```