# ¿Cómo validar un login en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, validación

Buenas tardes,

Este es mi codigo,

```
 <?php
$usuario = $_POST['nnpmbre'];
$pass = $_POST['npassword'];

if (empty($usuario) || empty($pass)) {
  # code...
  header("location: ../OtrasPAginas/Inicio.html ");
  exit();
}
echo $_POST['nnpmbre'];
echo $_POST['npassword'];

mysqli_connect('localhost','root','12345678') or die ("Error al Conectar, Usuario o clave incorrectos" .mysqli_error());
mysqli_select_db('web_juegos') or die("Error, lo sentimos en estos momentos tenemos problemas en la base de datos porfavor intente mas tarde" .mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * from User0 where User0 ='".$usuario ."'");

 ?>
```

Y al parecer olvide como hacer la validacion de la contraseña, ya que me conecta asi este la contraseña mal

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: ire a almorzar ya vuelvo

Comment: El código que compartes me pone algo nervioso. Por una parte parece ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL (lo cuál debería preocuparte mucho); por otra parte pareces tener una tabla que contiene un campo del mismo nombre (lo que hace la sentencia SQL bastante confusa). Te recomendaría que no entraras a hacer logins hasta que no tengas algunos conceptos de programación y seguridad informática claros. Aparte, ese código parece leer los datos del usuario, pero no muestra la comprobación/validación, que es donde dices que tienes problemas. Falta código esencial en la pregunta.

Comment: Esta pregunta es duplicada a mi parecer, tienes una practicamente igual aquí [¿Cómo hacer un login en PHP?] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64533/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-un-login-en-php/64577#64577), aparte no fuiste ni para corregir el código, que lo raro es que te funcione algo ta y como esta en esta pregunta.

Comment: primero , ya he hecho logins y e evitado el sql inyeccion, lo otro dije que eh olvidado como ahcer la validacion, pero ya yo he trabajado con segurida de logins, y no esta duplicada..... la pregunta :v @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: y mi pagina no esta en la web apenas la estoy creando :v

Comment: Me mantengo en mi comentario: No importa que lo hayas hecho bien una o un millón de veces, el código que acompaña a esta pregunta (que es lo único que podemos ver) no es bueno porque presenta problemas graves de seguridad y diseño. Si lo has hecho bien antes, ¿por qué ponerlo mal en la pregunta? Y si lo has hecho mal antes, ¿no preferirías que te lo dijeran en un comentario por aquí antes que un hacker que te haga la vida imposible?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ps te vuelvo a responder lo mismo, olvide como hacerlo la pregunta tiene es como validar un login en php osea, :v hay esta la pregunta porque eh olvidado como hacerlo pero ya lo hice bien :v a te cuento XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de hacer el select pones un if...

```
         if($pass === $result['password'] && $usuario === $result['User0']){
               //Haces header o un echo si haces peticion por ajax a la ruta de la vista que accede.
         }else{
              //Haces header o un echo si haces peticion por ajax a la ruta de la vista de logueo nuevamente ya que no coincide el password o usuario.
         }
```

Pero debes tener en cuenta que hay que codificar el password para que no sea muy vulnerable, el select a la BD no lo debes hacer así directamente en el archivo, intenta hacer algo mas seguro.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos opciones, obtener de tu variable result el campo password y compararlo con el que está ingresando el usuario o compararlo directamente en tu sentencia sql:

```
"SELECT * from User0 where User0 ='"$usuario"' and password = '"$pass"'
```

Comment: Faltan los puntos de concatenación